# Store multiple textarea data in database from a metabox

Tags: metabox

I am building Metabox in WordPress, and I have added two TextArea with JSON Data . but When I Click on Save button than only first textarea data can be stored in database insted of both textarea.

```
<div class="row output-container">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Output:</h2>
                        <form class="form">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="json-output" id="json-output" rows="5" style="width:100%" ><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'json-output', true);?></textarea>
                        </form>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="row output-container">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Output:</h2>
                        <form class="form">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="json-output-cat" id="json-output-cat" rows="5" style="width:100%" ><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'json-output-cat', true);?></textarea>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my Html code , below is WordPress Function

```
update_post_meta($post_id, "json-output", $_POST["json-output"]);
update_post_meta($post_id, "json-output-cat", $_POST["json-output-cat"]);
```

[image]